# Not Getting Expected Value when Performing Calculation on Date-based variables

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get a decimal value of the `DaysRemainingInMonth` / `DaysInMonth` in a `SELECT` statement, however I always get a `0` value in the column when executing the statement.

It seems so strange since it's essentially a simple division exercise:

```
declare @DaysinMonth int = DAY(EOMONTH(GETDATE())) -- 31
declare @DaysRemaining int = @DaysinMonth - DAY(GETDATE()) -- 24

SELECT 
      (DAY(EOMONTH(GETDATE())) - DAY(GETDATE())) as DaysRemaining
      ,@DaysinMonth as DaysinMonth 
      ,@DaysRemaining as DaysRemaining2
      , cast( (24/31) as decimal(18,10)) as Col1 -- Try casting and hard-coded values??
      , @DaysRemaining / @DaysinMonth as col2
      , 10 / 2 as WorkingExample
```

Surely I should get `0.774194...` as an answer for `Col1` at the very least? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: `(24/31)` will give you an integer value, you need to cast one of them to decimal.

Comment: @DavidG You're kidding me! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As both operands are integers, the result is also an integer with the fractional part cut off.

Convert one (or all) of the operands to `decimal`, so that the result is also a `decimal`.

```
...
, convert(decimal, 24) / 31 as Col1
, convert(decimal, @DaysRemaining) / @DaysinMonth as col2
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try casting both the values to numeric

```
declare @DaysinMonth int = DAY(EOMONTH(GETDATE())) -- 31
declare @DaysRemaining int = @DaysinMonth - DAY(GETDATE()) -- 24

SELECT 
      (DAY(EOMONTH(GETDATE())) - DAY(GETDATE())) as DaysRemaining
      ,@DaysinMonth as DaysinMonth 
      ,@DaysRemaining as DaysRemaining2
      , cast( (24/31) as decimal(18,10)) as Col1 -- Try casting and hard-coded values??
      , cast(@DaysRemaining as numeric) / cast(@DaysinMonth as numeric) as col2
      , 10 / 2 as WorkingExample
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your unexpected results is the [implicit data type conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) and when you divide two integer values, the result will be also an integer.

You may try with the following code (again with implicit data type conversion made by the server):

```
declare @DaysinMonth int = DAY(EOMONTH(GETDATE())) -- 31
declare @DaysRemaining int = @DaysinMonth - DAY(GETDATE()) -- 24

SELECT 
    (DAY(EOMONTH(GETDATE())) - DAY(GETDATE())) as DaysRemaining,
    @DaysinMonth as DaysinMonth,
    @DaysRemaining as DaysRemaining2, 
    (1.0 * 24 / 31) as Col1,
    1.0 * @DaysRemaining / @DaysinMonth as col2,
    10 / 2 as WorkingExample
```

Or use explicit data type conversion:

```
declare @DaysinMonth int = DAY(EOMONTH(GETDATE())) -- 31
declare @DaysRemaining int = @DaysinMonth - DAY(GETDATE()) -- 24

SELECT 
    (DAY(EOMONTH(GETDATE())) - DAY(GETDATE())) as DaysRemaining,
    @DaysinMonth as DaysinMonth,
    @DaysRemaining as DaysRemaining2, 
    CONVERT(decimal, 24) / 31  as Col1,
    CONVERT(decimal, @DaysRemaining) / @DaysinMonth as col2,
    10 / 2 as WorkingExample
```

Output:

```
DaysRemaining   DaysinMonth DaysRemaining2  Col1     col2           WorkingExample
24              31          24              0.774193 0.77419354838  5
```